# Why deploying fargate over a load balancer service takes more time than its own service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, service, load-balancing, aws-fargate

I'm making some basic architecture with some backend and frontend docker containers.

I started deploying a backend container, defined a task with AWS Fargate and configured its own service. The time of the deployments took about 2 minutes, but now I have a Network Load Balancer service with target group targeting to my container, and the deploy takes about 6-10 minutes, is it normal?

This deploy time is not bothering me but, while I'm studying this technology, this is getting a little slow (for example against a kubernetes cluster), my plan is to have a bigger architecture with back, front, db and auto-scalers, just for learning.

Comment: Fargate is a deployment target for ECS and EKS. Which one are you using? Pointing a load balancer at an ECS service shouldn't increase the deployment time of that service any, but you may be seeing the load balancer take a long time to register the new service as healthy. That can be mitigated somewhat by adjusting your load balancer's health check settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sharing your configuration **(CloudFormation Template)** or some screenshots its hard to say exactly what is causing this issue but I can point you to some areas that could cause longer deployments.

- Possibly have a default health heck interval set to 30 seconds. This means that it waits **30** seconds to carry out another check on the TCP port.

  - You can reduce this to **10** seconds to speed up health checks
- Possibly have the default health check healthy threshold set as 3. This coupled with the default check interval adds around **90** seconds to stabilise a container and return a healthy status.
- Deploying a single container and not having **Cross-Zone** load balancing enabled and also having round robin routing algorithm.

  - This setup can fail the health check and then the threshold count starts again and you need **3** in a row to return a **healthy status**.
- Lastly, Fargate because there is no image caching the pull time is a bit longer than ECS backed by EC2 instances so can also add to the deployment time.

With all the above configured correctly you can get back a few minutes usually on a Network Load Balancer target group deployment but they are usually a bit slower than **Application Load Balancer** deployments.

If your app does not require a Network Load Balancer its recommended to use an application load balancer. An application load balancer goes much deeper and is capable of determining availability based on not only a successful HTTP GET of a particular page but also the verification that the content is as was expected based on the input parameters.

Comment: Hi ! The first and third point were important to me. Also, I didn't know Fargate always pulls the images, thank you! But, due to this question, your explanation makes sense to me and I can understand a NLB cares about other configurations. I will use ALB now I have basics. Thanks!